# FreeBSD i386 sendfile for large files

Tags: freebsd, x86

Is there any kind of sendfile64 for FreeBSD i386?
Can't find anything like this in FreeBSD sys calls reference.

Comment: Doesn't `sendfile` work for you? FreeBSD doesn't have 64-suffixed calls at all.

Comment: @arrowd  it works but has a certain limitation on 32 system: off_t and size_t are 4 bytes long, so `sendfile` cannot handle files larger than 4Gb. On linux there is a sendfile64/fstat64... that solve the issue, so I want to know if there any solution for FreeBSD or to get a confirmation from people experienced in domain that there is no way to use `sendfile` on 32bit system for large files.

Comment: What version of FreeBSD are you running? I was pretty sure that `off_t` and `size_t` were 64-bit on BSDs [for a long time now](http://comp.unix.bsd.freebsd.misc.narkive.com/dgcyeocO/definition-of-off64-t): what do you get if you print out `sizeof(off_t)` and `sizeof(size_t)`?

Comment: It outputs 4. I used thit port https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/VM-IMAGES/11.1-RELEASE/i386/Latest/

Comment: Correct: sizeof(off_t) is 8, so the issue can be resolved as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427273/46624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even on i386, off_t is 64bit. Only size_t is 32bit. If you call sendfile() you can specify nbytes = 0, and it will send the entire file. The offset is 64bit, so if you need to send only part of a large file, you'd have to loop calling sendfile() with 32bit sized chunks, and increasing the offset.

In general you should not have any problems handling large files even on FreeBSD/i386.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is what I end up with.